# Can I use a lower voltage adapter for my Philips Sound Bar?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

Edit: I connected the 19 V 4.73 A HP laptop adaptor to my sound bar and it is working perfectly. No humming or distortion. I am so happy. I am running it for long 8 continuous hours and its fine. :)

I have a burnt Philips 21 V 3.09 A SMPS adapter of my sound bar. It seems impossible to repair it and the replacement adapter is not available.

I have a spare HP laptop 19 V adapter rated 90 watts. Can I use it on my sound bar?

What will be the drawback or will it damage the sound bar?

Sound bar model: Philips HTL2163B/76
Link: https://www.philips.com.au/c-p/HTL2163B_79/soundbar-speaker

Original burnt power supply:

[image]

Supply I want to use:

[image]

Comment: To even attempt an answer at this question, we would need to know more about the soundbar itself.  Please link a manual or datasheet for it.

Comment: I have now added the sound bar model : Philips HTL2163B/76

Comment: Damage might occur if your new 19V is higher than the original 21V. The maximum undistorted output power will be a little less than before.

Comment: An important symbol on the Phillips adapter (the square-in-a-square) indicates that it is double insulated, i.e. does not connect to third-prong ground.   That feature is NOT indicated on the other adapter.   Because ground wiring can cause hum, a double-insulated (no ground connection) adapter would be preferable.

Comment: I connected the 19 V 4.73 A HP laptop adaptor to my sound bar and it is working perfectly. No humming or distortion. I am so happy. I am running it for long 8 continuous hours and its fine. :)